# Turn flashlight on/off In QRcodeScanner React native

Tags: android, react-native, flashlight

im using `react-native-qrcode-scanner` and what i want to do is : when user press on a flashlight icon flashLight go on
i done this :

```
<QRCodeScanner
        showMarker
        onRead={this.onSuccess.bind(this)}
        cameraStyle={{ height: SCREEN_HEIGHT }}
        cameraProps={{ flashMode: this.state.flashLight ? RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on : RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off, captureAudio: false }}
```

camera prop works
but when i change the state.flashLight (true or false) the flashLight not change

any Idea how change camera prop with state ??

Comment: did you try to use ```this.scanner.reactivate()``` after the icon clicked ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on
```

with:

```
RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.torch
```

Does the flashlight turn on now?

Answer (score 4):

Using react-native-qrcode-scanner **version 1.2.2** or above

Try to use **flashMode** instead of **cameraProps**.

Here is a working example:

```
      <QRCodeScanner
              ref={(node) => { this.scanner = node }}
              onRead={this.onSuccess.bind(this)}
              showMarker
              cameraStyle={{ height: SCREEN_HEIGHT }}
              customMarker={this.renderCustomMarker}
              flashMode={this.state.torchEnable ? RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.torch : RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
              />
```

**this.state.torchEnable** is a boolean variable used to set flash on or off.

For more info read the [Github repo](https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner) description on **Methods > flashMode**