# Turn flashlight on/off In QRcodeScanner React native - Alternative Solution

Tags: android, react-native, android-camera, qr-code, flashlight

[Turn flashlight on/off In QRcodeScanner React native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918898/turn-flashlight-on-off-in-qrcodescanner-react-native)

I have follow the tutorial above, but still not working. It doesn't turn on the flash on pressing the touch opacity.

The issue is the same as the problem send, but the solution for him not work for me, don't know why.

**UPDATE**
I have found a solution, if the other post not work for you, you should try this step by step. Probably it will merged in a future PR in react-native-qrcode-scanner, but for now this should solve.

```
import QRCodeScanner from "react-native-qrcode-scanner";
import { RNCamera } from "react-native-camera"
```

Props on QRCodeScanner:

```
cameraStyle={{ height: SCREEN_HEIGHT }}
cameraProps{{ flashMode: this.state.isFlashOn ? RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.torch : RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off, captureAudio: false }}
customerMarker={this.renderCustomMarker} />
```

The Button:

```
<TouchOpacity activeOpacity={1} onPress={() => {
       this.setState({isFlashOn: !this.state.isFlashOn});
       this.scanner.reactivate();
    }}>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to me was in: 
https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner/issues/117

Thanks to @Albert0405!

Here is the fix from @Albert0405 for my problem:

**1)** Go to **node_modules** and find **react-native-qrcode-scanner** folder and open **index.js**

**2)** find **_renderCamera()** and then on the Camera component, change this

```
<Camera
   type={cameraType}
   flashMode={this.props.flashMode} // Just add this line
   style={[styles.camera, this.props.cameraStyle]}
   onBarCodeRead={this._handleBarCodeRead.bind(this)}
>
    {this._renderCameraMarker()}
</Camera>
```

**3)** Last step is to you use the Flash on your project

```
import QRCodeScanner from "react-native-qrcode-scanner";
import { RNCamera } from "react-native-camera";

<QRCodeScanner
    flashMode={this.state.isFlashOn ? RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.torch : RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
/>
```

The cameraProps does not work for me. So I replaced it with the code flashMode above.

***RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.torch*** - Turn on Flashlight
**RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off** - Turn off Flashlight
**flashMode** is a field to set Flash on RNCamera

What this step by step does is enable **flashMode** to be set from react-native-qrcode-scanner.

Reference: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md

UPDATE: react-native-qrcode-scanner version 1.2.2+ has this change implemented. My PR was merged and available to all users, to see how to use please read the Read Me for git repo.

Comment: Add a PR to https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner to fix this missing props on the camera from QR Code Scanner module.